# Hands on std::variant, does it exist?

Tags: c++, c++17

Considering http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0088r2.html I tried:

```
#include <variant>
int main (){}
```

Compiling on macOS I get:

```
$ g++ -std=c++1z main.cpp 
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'variant' file not found
#include <variant>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiler used:

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
```

Where is it?

Comment: looks like it is using version 4.2.1 which is way out of date.  You'll want version 7.1 for the most C++17 support.

Comment: May I update without breaking macOS? How should I proceed? I think I installed an update to Xcode last week. Where are you reading 4.2.1 (I see 8.1.0)?

Comment: `--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`

Comment: Xcode versions are not clang versions.  Xcode doesn't advertise "we are a wrapper for another compiler, and our version is ancient".  Annoying.

Comment: Try it as `#include <experimental/variant>` then it would be used as `std::experimental::variant<some_type>`

Comment: Really? I got main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'experimental/variant' file not found
#include <experimental/variant>
         ^
1 error generated.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is not real g++. @AlexZywicki There's no such thing as `<experimental/variant>` in the world.